# How do I cache with the ElementAPI plugin?

Tags: cache, plugin-elementapi

I'm replacing some templates with the ElementAPI plugin.

In my templates, I would use the `cache` tag, and rely on Craft to handle invalidation when the elements changed.

How can I achieve a similar thing now that I'm using the ElementAPI plugin?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ElementAPI plugin itself doesn't seem to offer a caching solution, but there is a fork from a guy which has implemented a caching option `cache` and `cacheTime`:
https://github.com/theolampert/ElementAPI

**Update**: They have introduced a new [`cache`](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/v1#cache) option in the official [ElementAPI](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/v1) plugin (version 1.5).

Comment: Any tips how to bust the cache? For either of these forks?

Comment: use `craft->cache->delete('routename')`

Answer (score 4):

I was also very interested in this, so i forked the repo from theoplampert and added some extra features. You can find it here, https://github.com/jacobnijgh/ElementAPI. This fork allows you to not only cache the results but also the paginated results just what we needed in our case for loading some results with AJAX.